# sudo apt-get update error

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I use a distribution based on ubuntu and when updating my repository I get this

```
Err: 1 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Could not resolve "us.old-releases.ubuntu.com"
Err: 2 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Could not resolve "us.old-releases.ubuntu.com"
Could not resolve "us.old-releases.ubuntu.com"
Ign: 4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err: 5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
404 not found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Obj: 6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt / stable / InRelease
Ign: 9 http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi bionic Release.gpg
Reading package list ... Done
E: The repository "http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release" does not have a Post file.
N: You cannot update a repository like this safely and therefore it is disabled by default.
N: See the apt-secure (8) man page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.
E: The launch file from http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/dists/bionic/Release is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 35min 28s). Updates will not be applied for this repository.
```

Comment: There is no `us.old-releases.ubuntu.com`. There's just ``old-releases.ubuntu.com``

Comment: Is `bionic` really in `old-releases`?

Comment: See also: [AskUbuntu: `apt-get update` cannot find Ubuntu servers](https://askubuntu.com/q/29071/327339)

Answer (score 1):

**1) try it**

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

**2) second**

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
```

after that try again

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

**3) in last case**

Try to create new `vim /etc/apt/sources.list` with new source list. 
And check it out: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/